# Matrix similarity equivalent to same characteristic polynomial and same geometric multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm wondering whether the similarity of two square matrices is equivalent to them having the same characteristic polynomial and the same geometric multiplicity for each eigenvalue. It's obvious in case they are both diagonalizable but is it true when they are not? I can't seem to figure it out, any help would be nice.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form Take a look at this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's more complex than that. One can find  matrices with the same (single) eigenvalue, the same characteristic and minimal polynomials, yet non-similar.

There exists a complete set of `similarity invariants` which *characterises* similar matrices. It is based on the *structure theorem for finitely generated modules over P.I.D.s* :

> For any finitely generated module $M$ over a P.I.D. $R$, there is a sequence of elements $(d_1,d_2,\dots , d_n)$ such that
>    $$M\simeq R/(d_1)\times R/(d_2)\times\dots\times R/(d_n) \quad\text{and}\quad d_1\mid d_2\mid \dots\mid d_n $$
>   Furthermore the $d_i$s are unique but for a unit factor. They're called the *invariant factors* of the module $M$.

Now let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over the field $K$. The vector space $K^n$ can be seen as a $K[X]$-module in the following way: for any vector $u\in K^n$, one sets
$$X\cdot u\overset{\text{def}}{=} Au. $$
One easily checks this turns $K^n$ into a finitely generated module over the P.I.D. $K[X]$. The invariant factors of this module are the *similarity invariants of the matrix* $A$.

You can have more details on [Wikipedia.fr](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariants_de_similitude) if you can read French. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem be a similar (;o)) Wikipedia article in English.

Comment: Thank you very much but unfortunately I am not able to understand your answer as I am just a student in my first semester of linear algebra. Would there be another way to explain it?

Comment: This is indeed beyond first semester linear algebra (in France, this is in the curriculum of 3rd year students). I'm afraid there's no other other way. Maybe the structure theorem will be best understood if you take a look at the structure theorem for [finitely  generated abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group), which is the initial version of the general theorem.  In any case, you may retain your criterion doesn't suffice to characterise similar matrices.

Comment: I looked into both articles (although I understand the French words but not really the whole mathematical context) and it was quite overwhelming. Obviously I have a long way to go to finally grasp it. Thanks a lot anyway, you still helped me! And by the way, how do I show that two square non-diagonalizable matrices are similar then?

Comment: If they have the same Jordan normal form, they're similar. Do you know about Jordan normal form?

Comment: My lecturer told us of its existence but we won't deal with it. Therefore we are not allowed to use it and I don't really know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe mimicking the procedure to find the normal Jordan form: for each eigenvalue value $\lambda$, consider the sequence of subspaces: $\;\{0\}\varsubsetneq \ker(A-\lambda I)\varsubsetneq\ker(A-\lambda I)^2\varsubsetneq\dots\varsubsetneq\ker(A-\lambda I)^r= \ker(A-\lambda I)^{r+1}=\cdots$ (the sequence is increasing first, then stabilises). If the  sequences for $A$ and $B$ have the same structure, the matrices are similar.

Comment: Could you please explain to me why this implication is true? I am sorry for not seeing your point.

Comment: That's not easy. Roughly speaking, it's the basis for the effective computation of a Jordan basis. The dimensions of these subspaces yields information on the number of Jordan blocks of a given size. But with the tools you have at your disposal as a first year student, I don't see how it can solved, except by brute force, trying to find, given two matrices $A$ and $B$, whether there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $AP=PB$, solving a system of $n2$ linear equations, with $n^2$ unknowns.

Comment: Thanks, I've solved it just now!